# Правильно ли расставлены кавычки

Tags: кавычки

У меня есть любимое место. Оно называется "Три домика". Я люблю играть в " три домика"

Answer (score 3):

Судя по тому, что это больше похоже на упражнение, чем на связный текст, получается следующее: в первой фразе кавычки нужны, так как "Три домика" - это не прямое значение слов. Во второй - нет, так как название игры (если б было название местности, то был бы другой падеж; *в "Трёх домиках*).

Answer (score 0):

А что такое "три домика" в последней фразе?
Если это то же место, о котором говорится раньше, то *Я люблю играть в **"Три домика"***.

Хотя это еще надо посмотреть, если это топоним какой-то, то и кавычки в названии не нужны.